# Crafting writ not registering as completed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Yesterday I picked up a writ for jewelcrafting. The requirement was 2 pewter necklaces.

I crafted 1 of the most simple type (the least number of resources). The text appeared in the middle of the screen, updating my progress to 1/2 necklaces crafted.
The second necklace I crafted using the highest amount of pewter I could choose, resulting in a necklace my character can't equip yet. The text never appeared,  the quest progress remained 1/2.

I'm positive I crafted the correct item twice. I tried to craft another which didn't register either and even logged in and out and waited a few minutes. I'll need to try again later when I have mined more pewter.

My game installation is standard, no mods or changes. Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The second necklace I crafted using the highest amount of pewter I could choose

This is the problem. For some reason, items only count toward a writ if you craft them at the minimum level for their type. Make another level 1 pewter necklace and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen. Are you 100% sure both necklaces are identical? They have to be white quality with no traits (the level doesn't matter as long as it's the correct material). Also make sure you don't have any other items of the same quality/level crafted by another character in inventory.

If it still doesn't progress properly, keep the crafted items in your inventory, but abandon the quest and pick it up once again. It should complete straight away as long as the items were crafted by your character.

Comment: Pretty sure. At one moment I had 3 identical pewter necklaces, all 3 without a trait, only of different levels. I'll try your suggestion when I can.

Comment: I abandoned the quest, but I was given the quest to craft 3 rings instead. I'll need to wait for another day when necklaces are the quest objective again.

Comment: craft requests only mark as complete if the item is the most basic they can be - the same applies to armour and weapons (you have to use the minimum amount of materiales (and I think no traits either); Enchanting glyphs are created with Ta only - nothing higher; and jewelry is created at the simplest level requested.

Comment: @MeanGreen - craft them all at the same minimum level for the material - there is no benefit to crafting higher rated items for writs - they don't count at all.